# Colocar a primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúscula

Tags: java, android, regex

Quero padronizar o que o usuário digitou no edittext, colocando a primeira letra de cada palavra em maiúscula e o resto minúscula. Como faço isso?

A parte que seta as variáveis na classe modelo

```
Contato c = new Contato();
c.setNome(etNome.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma combinação de [`toUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--) para a primeira letra e  [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--) para que o restante da palavra seja todo minúsculo. Abstraindo isso em um método, fica assim:

```
public String toTitledCase(String str){

    String[] words = str.split("\\s");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        sb.append(words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Veja em funcionamento no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/WiYkP3).

Comment: Isso funcionou trocando a primeira letra da primeira palavra, gostaria que fizesse isso com todas palavras, poderia ajudar?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam palavras separadas por um espaço?

Comment: exaramente isso

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam veja a edição.

Comment: por curiosidade pra que serve o \\s no split?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam split quebra a string em um array de outras strings baseado em um separador que você passa como parametro. Neste caso, utilizei `\\s` que é a representação de espaço em regex, mas você pode alterar para `split(" ");` que funciona normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado quando eu uso split geral mente com o espaço mesmo não sabia que também poderia usar //s mas faz alguma diferença? qual é melhor?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam a representação literal é mais recomendada, ou seja, é melhor utilizar assim `split(" ")`, apesar que neste caso não há diferença de performance.

Comment: Para este caso é mais interessante usar o StringBuilder. xD

Comment: @acklay alterado, valeu pela dica :)

Comment: coloquei uma cláusula `if` ali no meio só pra não ficar com um espaço adicional no final da string `str` desnecessariamente

Answer (score 1):

Dessa maneira aceita apenas uma palavra ou uma frase composta

```
public class CamelCaseConverter {

    public Object converter(String nome) {
        char[] palavras = nome.toCharArray();
        
        
        for(int i = 1; i < palavras.length; i++) {
            //convertendo todas as letras para minúsculo para casos como tEsTe = teste
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(palavras[i])) {
                palavras[i] = Character.toLowerCase(palavras[i]);
            }
            //se o carácter anterior for espaço então o atual sera maiúsculo
            if(Character.isWhitespace(palavras[i - 1])) {
                palavras[i] = Character.toUpperCase(palavras[i]);
            }
        }
        //por fim a primeira letra de toda frase ou palavra será maiúscula
        palavras[0] = Character.toUpperCase(palavras[0]);
       
        //retorna o Array de char como String
        String nomeConvertido = new String(palavras);       
        
        return nomeConvertido;
    }

}
```

Fontes de pesquisa: https://www.guj.com.br/t/iniciais-maiusculas-em-cada-palavra-da-string/114502